# Regular expression for a list of numbers without other characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for a list of numbers in a text box with carriage returns and line feeds, but no other characters.

e.g.

```
1234 
5678 
5874 
3478
```

I have this:

```
Regex(@"\d\r\n${0,}?");
```

... but it is accepting commas when I paste them into my text box:

e.g.

```
1234,
5678
5874,
3478
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a lot is wrong with your Regex =)

- \d matches one number, not several
- $ matches the end of the line, {0,} means, that the symbol before it may appear zero or more times. But zero or more end of lines are not very useful.
- The ? is superfluous, I think.
- You are missing the start of line character.

Your regex matches the example you have given, because it matches the "8" in the second line.

Use this regex instead:

```
"^(\d*\r\n)*$"
```

Comment: @JamesW, it matches empty lines too, is that what you wanted? If not, replace the \d* with \d+

Answer (score 0):

Try * instead of {0,} - they mean the same thing.